# How to make a 1v1v1v1 game in Age of Empires 2: DE?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-de

Every time I try to make a game with multiple people it ends up being a team game. What lobby settings do I need to make it a FFA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your Team to <kbd>-</kbd>, the dash null value, instead of <kbd>?</kbd>:

[image: Screenshot of the AoE 2:DE Multiplayer lobby with a player's Team setting set to null, or the "-" character.]

Anyone whose Team is set to the null value will not be placed on a team with anyone else. The question mark value is random. This information is shown to you on hover of the button:

[image: A screenshot showing the tooltip which appears on hover of the Team selector button]